# R: Error in nchar(b64String) : invalid multibyte string, element 1

Tags: r

I am using `illuminaio::readIDAT` to read some idat files.

```
library(illuminaio)
dat <- readIDAT('1552034262_A_Grn.idat')
Error in nchar(b64String) : invalid multibyte string, element 1
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In grep(" __", r) : input string 47890 is invalid in this locale
2: In grep(" __", r) : input string 47891 is invalid in this locale
3: In grep(" __", r) : input string 47892 is invalid in this locale
4: In grep(" __", r) : input string 47893 is invalid in this locale
5: In grep(" __", r) : input string 47894 is invalid in this locale
6: In grep(">", r) : input string 47890 is invalid in this locale
7: In grep(">", r) : input string 47891 is invalid in this locale
8: In grep(">", r) : input string 47892 is invalid in this locale
9: In grep(">", r) : input string 47893 is invalid in this locale
10: In grep(">", r) : input string 47894 is invalid in this locale
```

This is my sessionInfo():

```
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: CentOS release 6.7 (Final)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] illuminaio_0.15.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] base64_2.0    openssl_0.9.4
```

I am getting this error but don't know how to debug it. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you forget a ' ? Try `readIDAT('1552034262_A_Grn.idat')`

Comment: That was a typo in the question. I have fixed it.

Comment: What OS and locale are you using?

Comment: Sounds like an encoding problem. What OS? What R version? Provide the output of `sessionInfo()`. It would be easier to help with a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Added my sessionInfo.